# Upgrading to Laravel Spark 6; Undefined Method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

I'm trying to iterate my way to the latest Laravel and Laravel Spark, currently tripping over an issue going from Laravel Spark 5 to 6. Loading my app, I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Spark\Spark::teamString() (View: /home/vagrant/my-project/resources/views/vendor/spark/auth/register-common.blade.php)
```

From what I can tell, I have the correct instance of Laravel Spark in my vendor folder, I've `composer dump-autoload` along with clearing the caches via `artisan`.

I have the following in `app.php` as per the instructions:

```
Laravel\Spark\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::class,
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\SparkServiceProvider::class,
```

Am I missing something obvious? What can I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue when upgrading my Spark project and the fix is changing any reference to Spark::teamString to Spark::teamsPrefix.

Answer (score 1):

Greg V is correct.  You need to change `teamString` to `teamsPrefix`.  This is because in Spark v6.0 `Spark::referToTeamsAs()` was changed to `Spark::prefixTeamsAs()`:  https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/upgrade

You can see the new methods in Spark's source (`ManageAppOptions.php` lines 141-160) and `teamString` and `referToTeamsAs` no longer exist:

```
    /**
     * Get the string used to describe teams.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function teamsPrefix()
    {
        return static::$teamsPrefix;
    }

    /**
     * Set the string used to describe teams.
     *
     * @param  string  $string
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prefixTeamsAs($string)
    {
        static::$teamsPrefix = $string;
    }
```